# passing data from view to controler and back

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC application and I have an index view where I pass model from controller to index view. The index action has no parameters. Now On view I have a jquery calendar. I want to change all the data on view when a date is selected. do I need to use different action method for this as current action method doesn't have parameter. or I can use same ? Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a DateTime parameter on that index view. You can then handle the case where it is null in the action:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime dateTime)
{
    if (dateTime == null)
        //Do default view
    else
        //Use date for view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a client-side event handler on the calendar, and call a different action on the controller via jQuery.ajax()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can create the same Action method to handle both:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DoThis() { }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoThis(FormCollection data) { }
```

It can be the same action, but it has to be a different action handler to handle the post to the server, where the post is from a form or a JQuery call.